# How can I access $event inside a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I can't seem to pass it as an attribute!

I can add an ng-click="function($event)" and pass $event that way to a controller function, but I would like to access it inside a directive.

The ultimate purpose is to stopPropagation() and/or preventDefault() of an element inside a directive instead of in a controller.

EDIT: I will post code accordingly

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button stop-toggle ng-click="testFunction($event)">
     click me
  </button>
  Hello, {{name}}!
</div>
```

---

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';

    $scope.testFunction = function($event){
       console.log("you can access the event here:", $event);
       $event.stopPropagation();
    }
}

myApp.directive('stopToggle', function(){
    return {
     link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        elem.bind('click', function(){
           console.log("how do i access the $event here??");
           // elem.stopPropagation();  // invalid function
           // elem.preventDefault();    // invalid function
        })

     }
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10656/

Comment: @AnirudhMangalvedhekar angular has no `on()` method

Comment: Please show relevant code. You can't set `$event` by itself in attribute because it is specific to an actual event that must occur first

Comment: elem.bind('click', function () {} is the substitute for on.. but in it I can access the scope, the element itself and the element's attributes; not the $event

Comment: sure it can.. the event is first argument of the event handler

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Without some code it is hard to direct you to best approach

Comment: Just pass event as parameter to function inside bind...elm.bind('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();.... })

Comment: Also better to use  .on() .bind is deprecated https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Anirudh, thanks, I missed that, what a silly brainfog :O! Post it as an answer, please.

Comment: Glad i could help..And i dont think you needed to put code for this question..It was self explanatory IMHO though

Comment: just move `$scope.testFunction` to the directive. Why not use `ng-click` there too?

Comment: @AnirudhMangalvedhekar Exactly. Thank you :) And '.on' it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    myApp.directive('stopToggle', function(){
       return {
             link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
             elem.on('click', function(e){
                 e.stopPropagation(); 
                 e.preventDefault();   
        })

     }
  }
});
```

Just pass event as an argument to the function inside .on()